# Inner join with 3 tables (the second and third "assigned" to the first - not all together)

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 3 tables which I would like to "inner join" - **but always to the first table**!

```
SELECT *
FROM scene_block AS sb
INNER JOIN roles AS r ON (sb.selected_block = r.id 
                         AND sb.block_type = 'role' 
                         AND r.id NOT IN (21))
INNER JOIN script_actors AS sa ON (sb.selected_block = sa.id 
                                  AND sb.block_type = 'actor')
WHERE 
    sb.scene_id = '1'
GROUP BY
    sb.id
ORDER BY 
    sb.position
```

The same query with LEFT JOIN returns all results as expected with the r.id 21 "NULL", the query with INNER JOIN returns 0 results (as there are all inner joins together)
[Result Left Join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGe6J.png)
But that's not what I want to achieve...

I would like to achieve, that If on scene_block "block_type='role'" the roles table is gonna be inner joined, if block_type='actor' the script_actors is gonna be inner joined... and the link between the rows is alsways scene_block.selected_id = .id

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE `scene_block` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `scene_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `block_type` enum('actor','role') NOT NULL,
  `selected_block` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `hideable` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `script_actors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `script_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `realname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `actorname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `color_live` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you show the tables with columns and values, it is unclear which column is being fetched from which table.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please add some minimal sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Hard to tell for sure without sample data and results, but I think that you need to turn one of your `left join` to an `inner join` (or maybe both).

Comment: 'Null instead of no output at all' - what do you mean by that?  Are you expecting empty strings instead of NULL values when there's not a row to match?  It looks like you are including all rows from `scene_block` whether there are any matching rows in the other two tables or not.  If there aren't matching rows in the other tables, the values for their columns will be NULL.  If you change to an inner join, you won't get those rows in your result at all.  If you're prefer empty strings, do `isnull(my_column_name, '')`

Comment: thanks for your answers - I've attached the tables and an explanation to my question =) thanks for helping me!

Comment: You could improve your feedback vastly by providing your details in text form for both structure (output of `show create table scene_block`) and contents (output from `select * from scene_block`) of your tables.

Comment: @cars10m thanks for the advice; I've changed that =)

Comment: @user3115056 I've attached the tables and a detailed explanation to my question - thanks for help.

Comment: Your join *will* be done relative to the *first* table, but now the first `INNER JOIN` will have the effect of keeping `id=21` out of the listing completely.

Answer (score 0):

Without having tested it on your data I presume that you get closer to your desired result if you use `INNER JOIN`s instead of `LEFT JOIN`s.

```
SELECT *
FROM scene_block AS sb
INNER JOIN roles AS r ON (sb.selected_block = r.id 
                     AND sb.block_type = 'role' 
                     AND r.id NOT IN (21))
INNER JOIN script_actors AS sa ON (sb.selected_block = sa.id 
                                   AND sb.block_type = 'actor')
WHERE 
sb.scene_id = '1'
GROUP BY
sb.id
ORDER BY 
sb.position
```

Comment: Agree - that's what I wrote above ^^ that was only for getting any output...
My problem is, that Inner join is always between all tables together... but I want a inner join between table 1 to 2 and table 1 to 3 ;)

Comment: I'd read up on what joins do because I think you are misunderstanding the way they work, stating that "the inner join is always all tables together" isn't accurate.

Comment: @Charleh I did! Unfortunately I can't figure it out... everything clear for me with multiple tables... but not with three tables on this specific condition...

Answer (score 0):

Inner joins don't work here, because a scene block type cannot be 'role' and 'actor' at the same time. You need outer joins to get either the role or the actor. Then add a condition to get rid of scene blocks that have no match.

```
SELECT *
FROM scene_block AS sb
LEFT JOIN roles AS r ON sb.selected_block = r.id 
                    AND sb.block_type = 'role' 
                    AND r.id <> 21
LEFT JOIN script_actors AS sa ON sb.selected_block = sa.id 
                             AND sb.block_type = 'actor'
WHERE sb.scene_id = 1
AND (sa.id IS NOT NULL OR r.id IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY sb.position;
```

Comment: That's it!! =)) So easy - I searched in the wrong direction ^^ thx!

Comment: I'm glad this solves your problem. If there can be multiple actors or roles per scene block, you may want to change your `ORDER BY` clause to `ORDER BY sb.position, COALESCE(r.position, sa.position)`.

Comment: Next time you write a request you should provide sample data with its expected result. I bet someone would have given you this answer the minute after posting that :-)